# Decoupling In-App-Billing from Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, billing

All tutorials I could find on Android In-App-Billing V3 assume you have one single activity that handles everything billing related. In my case there are multiple activities which will need access to the billing.
How would I handle such a thing most elegantly?

One example problem I stumbled upon:
When working with the Google billing helper classes you always hand over the current activity as a parameter. Later callbacks (e.g. onActivityResult) are called on that activity. But what if the active activity changes all the time? Do I have to shut down and re-initialize the billing all the time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But what if the active activity changes all the time? Do I have to
>   shut down and re-initialize the billing all the time?

There is nothing bad in it. Connecting to a service is very fast. Most important is to be able to handle onActivityResult() callback when activity starts again.

> How would I handle such a thing most elegantly?

I'm not sure which kind of application you write. If it's a game, then most likely it consists of a single activity and there is no problem anyway. If it is other kind of application with multiple activities, then in my opinion, it's a good idea to have a single activity, where user is able to see all the in-app products (bought and to buy). This is like an "internal store" activity. This activity can connect to the billing service. Other activities should forward to "internal store" where user can read more about an in-app product and decide to buy it. I find it very convenient.

Another approach would be to implement you billing logic in a Fragment which can be reused in every activity. You just need to override `onActivityResult()` and forward result to that Fragment. This is how I implemented it in my app.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great information. I have a question, how about accessing the InAppBilling code from another activity? I can't get it to work

Comment: Could you post your example Fragment with billing please? Thanks.

Comment: Fast to connect to a service, ok, but what about the impact on the device?  Does it involve communication with a server?

Comment: @WilliamJockusch IAB v3 allow to query for product as frequently as needed. First time, when there is no data on products and purchases, billing service will make a server call. Each next call will read data stored on device. It's stated like that in IAB v3 documentation.

Comment: The simple fact that we can't launch a purchase in one activity and get the billing result in THIS activity only in the "onPurchasesUpdated" function is stupid. I have an old app which use multiple activities and can perform a same purchase flow in seperate activities. Unlike saving a local reference to the current billing flow and cancel it whenever the process failed or user canceled it, I can't consume properly this purchase safely without performing this action twice (or x time an activity can handle theses skudetails) and that's just a bad design at first.

Answer (score 0):

Think a bit outside of the example box. It is not related to your problem only, but is general.

I would use a notification system, because you have 1 publisher and many listeners needed(your case 2).
One, ugliest method can be ( but fastest to write) :

1. make a fake activity (even invisible, whatever)
2. copy-paste the examples code which works there
3. hack a bit that working code and add listeners, which takes parameters as your real activity
4. notify when needed your instances, when needed

5th up-vote if helped or liked :)

Comment: Hm, creating a fake activity is not that easy. The only way to create an activity is to start it via the Android lifecycle, right? In that case the activity wouldn't be fake anymore but be actually on the screen ;-)

Comment: how hard it for you to make invisible an activity?

Comment: I think that defeats the purpose of decoupling business logic from the view (activities).